# Automatic excel cell fill up from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Here's the situation:

I have two excel sheets.

The first sheet contains a table of product codes and product descriptions (Two columns A and B).
I have a second sheet where someone is supposed to enter the product code and automatically have the next cell fill up with the product description and the cell next to it with the time.

I was wondering if that's do-able without VBA? If so, can someone give me start.

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the first cell that you want to auto fill have an IF statement, where if the cell has no value, nothing happens, and anything other than that gets a calculation. 
Using A2:B100 as a Range if you have a header Row.  Adjust to your own needs, of course.

[IF FUNCTION](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-function-HP010342586.aspx)
'IF (condition, result if true, result if false)'

[VLOOKUP FUNCTION](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)
'VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,range_lookup)'

```
=If($A1 = "", "", VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$100,2))
```

The next cell over would have something similar:

```
=IF($A1 = "", "", NOW())
```

This will get you the time.  You will also have to have the cell format set to Time.
There is a problem with that.  The screenshot below illustrates it.

It will just keep refreshing with the current time over and over.  I would use a bit of VBA to solve that by setting the value property instead of a formula.

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(row,col).Value = Now()
```

You could copy and paste the value into another cell.  Just the value.  Not the formula.

Or you could [check out this article:](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/01/08/timestamps-excel-formula-help/)  about generating Time Stamps.

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

edit: included VBA solution